# How can prevent iTunes from copying app purchases/updates from my iPhone, while keeping sync?

Tags: backup, sync, itunes, iphone, ios

I back my iPhone up to my computer. I consider this a safer, more complete, and cheaper option than iCloud backup.

In general, this is fine, but I have noticed the “copying app purchases from iPhone” phase can take *forever* – certainly over half an hour. (This is especially true when it’s been a week since my last sync.)

And it’s nearly pointless: these are usually just newer versions of apps iTunes already has, but more importantly, I don’t much care if iTunes has these apps in the first place. Should I restore my backup onto this or a replacement iPhone, my phone should be able to download most of those apps from the App Store, I would think. Sure, some apps could have been removed from the store. I’m okay with that.

So tell me – is there some way to ask iTunes to stop wasting its time by copying over all the apps from my phone?

(To be clear: iTunes should still be backing up my apps’ *data*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has fulfilled your wish here - iTunes 9.x and later does not migrate applications between your phone and computer, per [this article](https://www.macworld.com/article/3125509/iphone-ipad/more-on-backing-up-your-ios-device.html):

> With iOS 9 or later, apps will not sync or transfer to iTunes via
>   Transfer Purchases. If you would like to download your apps to your
>   iTunes library, make sure to turn on Automatic Downloads for your
>   iTunes purchases. You can also download past purchases.

iOS 12.7 further reduces this functionality ([link](http://osxdaily.com/2017/09/13/itunes-12-7-update-removes-app-store/)):

> The new version of iTunes adds support for iOS 11 while simultaneously
>   removing the iOS App Store from being included in iTunes.
>   Additionally, iTunes 12.7 removes the ability to sync iOS apps and
>   ringtones on an iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch via iTunes on the desktop.